# Accessing variables in different classes in Android

Tags: java, android

So say a user enters a total in an EditText field in my Incomings class, I then want this to be passed to my Results class. How do I go about this in Android? I know the best way is to use Accessor methods.
My Incomings class:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String userLoan = etLoan.getText().toString();
String userGrant = etGrant.getText().toString();
String userFirst = etFirst.getText().toString();

float fUserLoan = Float.parseFloat(userLoan);
float fUserGrant = Float.parseFloat(userGrant);
float fUserFirst = Float.parseFloat(userFirst);

float totalIncomings = fUserLoan + fUserGrant + fUserFirst;

Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Outgoings.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

My results class has a blank function and will calculate the totals
I have tried using accessor methods in my MainAcivity class:

```
public float getTotalOutgoings() {
    return totalOutgoings;
}

public void setTotalOutgoings(float totalOutgoings) {
    this.totalOutgoings = totalOutgoings;
}

public float getTotalIncomings() {
    return totalIncomings;
}

public void setTotalIncomings(float totalIncomings) {
    this.totalIncomings = totalIncomings;
}

public float getTotalResult() {
    return totalResult;
}

public void setTotalResult(float totalResult) {
    this.totalResult = totalResult;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The best way for Activity -> Activity data passing is by passing Intent extras.

Comment: @Adam yes you should pass data using intent in android.

Comment: @TGMCians Heh I still need to wake up. But then the question is, where is Results called from?

Comment: Sorry, once the user clicks a button then the an outgoings page comes up, the user fills that information out and then clicks results page which shows the results

Comment: @A--C he made a regular class and want to call settter and getter method to set and get value. Its good approach for web development not android. I am agree with your point. Outgoings is second activity look in the code.

Comment: @AdamAltinkaya but then the results page should be an Activity, not a plain Object, it's a separate screen.

Comment: @AdamAltinkaya Please clear your more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Intent extras:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Outgoings.class);
intent.putExtra ("total",totalIncomings);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then access in your next Activity with

```
Intent i = getIntent();
float totalComings = i.getFloatExtra("total",-1.0);
```

Now about your Results class. It depends exactly what you want to do with that class. If all you need is a simple calculation, make a static method. And data passing is usually the other way around. The Activity calls a data class, gives it data, *then* the data class does whatever it needs to do and returns the result to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Bundle bd = new Bundle();  
bd.putFloat("key",value);  
intent.putExtras(bd);  
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

On other class
    Bundle bund= getIntent().getExtras();
    float value= bd.getFloat("key");

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to call a function on your MainActivity?

```
MainActivity m = (MainActivity) getActivity();
m.setTotalIncomings(XXX);
```